# How to redirect user to another page in react on handleSubmit if I use class component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to redirect the user at the end of the handleSubmit function

```
class Singup extends Component {

  ...

  handleSubmit = async (e) => {

    ...

    useNavigate(("/"));

    **// I want to redirect user here**

};
  render() {

  ...

  }
}
```

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: Means what you want can you explain in detail?

Comment: @PriyenMehta handleSubmit is called when I click the button and I want it to redirect to the home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this (Also corrected class name spelling):

You have to use **Navigate** component with state for class component and **react-router-dom (version 6).**

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

class Signup extends Component {

 state = { user: false };

 handleSubmit = async (e) => {

  // Your code

  this.setState({ user: true });
  **// I want to redirect user here**

};
```

In Render part use Navigate component like this:

```
{this.state.user && (
      <Navigate to="/" replace={true} />
    )}
```

Comment: I can't use const in class component <<The 'const' modifier can only be used in TypeScript files.>>

Comment: I updated answer, Please check.

Comment: I need redirectıon to be in handleSubmit otherwise the form won't send

Comment: Yes, Please try once if user state update to true (It will update in handleSubmit event) then and only then it will redirect.

Comment: where exactly should I put it?
If I put it just in the form I get a huge number of different errors including "user is not defined"

Comment: You have to use this.state.user -> and put in render method after your parent div.

Comment: If I put it anywhere in the render -> return I got this error "POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=[api] 400"

If I put it outside of the return I got "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected."

Comment: Ah, yes, it works, I just made one mistake at first, thank you very much kind man

Comment: Ok, this works, unlike other methods which I tried in typescript when navigating after successful POST operation. It just feels way too more than it should be for React.